# Why the compiler cannot deduce the template arguments from std::make_shared?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, make-shared

I have this simple question from an exercise in "C++ primer, 5th ed":

> Exercise 16.38: When we call make_shared (§ 12.1.1, p. 451), we have to provide an explicit template argument. Explain why that argument is needed and how it is used.

I've tried, then I've seen some answers and suggestions, but I'm not convinced yet.

Some said:

> The argument is probably need for the return type which cannot be deduced from the arguments supplied in the function call (i.e. `make_shared<int>` returns a `shared_ptr<int>`).
>
> Alternatively the function body of `make_shared` needs to know what type to allocate to dynamic memory which is not deducible from the arguments supplied.

But I've tried this code on my own:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vec(T x...)
{
    return std::vector<T>(x);
}

int main()
{
   auto vi = make_vec(77);
   std::cout << vi.size() << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, my `make_vec` works without explicit template arguments, while `make_shared()` cannot. Why is that?

Comment: As an aside, nice way to combine C++ Templates and non-template varargs to confuse yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most variants of [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which return a `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<U[]>` - no parameter has type `T`. Examples:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
template<class T>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( std::size_t N );
```

(where in the latter example, `T` must be `U[]` for some `U`).

Without a type-`T` parameter to those functions - how can you deduce `T` (or `U`)?

In your example, you *do* take a parameter of type `T` and can easily deduce the template argument.

Comment: I got it! As I've re-read your example I've seen that the type parameter T cannot be deducible from the arguments in the call thus it must be explicitly specified. is it right?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, that's right. Next time, please take a little more time to look at the official declarations of library functions - scrutinizing them often makes things clearer.

Comment: Yep I do agree with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_shared` looks like

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

And the reason `T` needs to be provided is because there is no way to know from `Args` what type of object to create.  Lets say you have

```
struct Foo1
{
    Foo1(int, int) {}
};

struct Foo2
{
    Foo2(int, int) {}
};
```

And then you do

```
auto foo_ptr = std::make_shared(42, 42);
```

There is no way to know if you should create a `Foo1` or a `Foo2`, so you need to provide the type of object you want to create.

Comment: Yes because `T` is the type of the object to construct which is not specified as the type of a parameter in the function thus cannot be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Maestro No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: Glad to have people that help like you!